# Unity Firebase Realtime Database Chaining LimitTo calls only executing last LimitTo

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to run a limit for the realtime database in Unity but it seems to be only executing the last LimitTo:

```
dbInstance.GetReference("mycollection")
     .LimitToLast(randomPromptIndex)
     .LimitToFirst(1)
     .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
```

It seems to ignore LimitToLast and only executes LimitToFirst in this situation. Is it possible to chain like this or no? Is there an elegant solution for this without killing performance?

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/H7pnQ3T6Dnk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use one `limit...` clause per query. The SDK is supposed to throw an exception when you call multiple, so I'd consider the fact that it doesn't do so a bug.

If you want to get the single item at `randomPromptIndex` before the end of the query results, you'll have to read all of those, and discard `randomPromptIndex - 1` of them in your application code.